# Programming in Toradex Colibri T20 evalutaion board

Tags: uart, led

I have with me the `toradex colibri evalutaion board` along with `colibri T20`. This is my first time I am developing applications for colibri. Lets say I want to make an application which send data using UART of board to PC and glow an LED. Now my question is should I start developing this on my laptop which has linux and eclipse installed or I can directly make this application on toradex(and if yes then how.?)

Also I didnt find any tutorial on Toradex website on how to start programming UART and GPIOs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general it is recommended to use cross compiling when working with ARM based systems. Your typical development PC has more performance/memory so you can faster build/change your program. Then you can use Ethernet/USB to deploy and debug your application on the target (Colibri).

Toradex has many samples and How Tos:
http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/getting-started-with-toradex-arm-modules

Comment: Thanks for giving me that link. I have licensed visual studio 2012. But they say you need vs2008 to do programming for wince7. Can you tell me any way of doing it in my vs2012 professional.Its a licensed so i dont want to loose it and purchase vs2008

Comment: Officially you should use VS2008, if you like to use a newer one you could use WEC 2013 which is supported by the latest Visual Studio Versions. WEC2013 is available for T30 and IMX6 and Vybrid Toradex products: https://www.toradex.com/computer-on-modules/colibri-arm-family. There are some workarounds to make VS2008 work with WEC7 but I think you still need would need the licence of VS2008 and debugging probably also does not work: http://geekswithblogs.net/WernerWillemsens/archive/2013/09/13/building-windows-ce-6-or-7-smart-device-application-with.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the great info.!